# How to insert and remove items into the list when scroll up/down on list in flutter?

Tags: android, listview, insert, dart, flutter

I want when the user **scrolls up** on a list, then to **insert** items at top of the list and **remove** items at bottom of the list.
How can I do this in **flutter**?

itemBuilder isn't good in list because that always inserts but never removes (or insert remove method into?).
Or I use sliverlist(how?) or enough use somehow scrollcontroller with ListView?
Which is the best way?

So:

- Which list use: ListView/AnimatedList/SliverList?
- How to handle scroll up/down on list?

The point is: I don't want add more 1000 items in same time, but only which is appear on display. And when user scrolling on list then add new item to children and remove old from children which is hidden. So list children only contains a few items which appear.

Comment: Please provide the code you got so far.

Comment: No code.I simple want create some kind of ListView or AnimatedList/SilverList and when scrolling on list then insert and remove item.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to remove the items? Are you worried that they'll consume too much resources, or is there some sort of unusual effect you're trying to achieve? What would you like to happen when the user tries to scroll back to see the items you removed?

Comment: When scroll back add again removed item.
I thought this was a simple problem: create dinamic list which add/reomve items when user scrolling.
Item adding and removing it's very easy with for example buttons. But I don't use buttons, I want to use scrolling and this is the essential part. So how can I handle scrolling ?

Comment: ListViewer.builder does exactly what you want. It will clean up the offscreen elements automatically for you.

Comment: @CollinJackson it doesn't clear the memory used by them, so if you load a lot of images (228 in my case), the app uses around 700mb of ram, showing only one of those images. I think that he's reffering to that case.

Comment: If you are getting your data from firestore, you can take a look at how to achieve pagination. It will be cheaper, and it will save alot of memory for you.

Answer (score 3):

Reacting to your comment you are interested in a lazy loading ListView which only builds it's children, when they are actually visible.

I think it would be best to have a look at [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html). In the description of ListView it is explicitly stated, that:

> The ListView.builder takes an IndexedWidgetBuilder, which builds the children on demand. This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

This sounds like the behaviour you want, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The rendering process of the ListView will render only visible items.

You should watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F26pbGaSzfM

Comment: I see this video before, but this is not good for me, because video use itemBuilder which only add new item to list children, but never remove.
So I don't want contain all item in list children, only few items which is appear, therefore not enough if I don't render items which is hide.

Comment: Ok, you should start by looking at the lifecylce of a widget and how Flutter works (https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1cw7A4HbvM_Abv320rVgPVGiUP2msVs7tfGbkgdrTy0I/edit#slide=id.g70d668005_2_22). Basically if you only want a list of 10 items you just have to build a list with thoses items, then you can update you list and call `setState` to refresh the view

Comment: Yes I know, the important thing I don't know **how handle scrolling**.

Comment: Don't know if there is a clean way to do this, but you can do inside itemBuilder, looking at the index, if the `index == list.length - 1` it means that you are at the end of the list